# Can I travel more than once on my Multi entry Schengen Visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I was given a Schengen Visa by the Greek embassy in Cape Town, valid for one year, duration of stay 90 days. I went to Greece last Sept for 10 days.  It says valid for all Schengen States.

Can I use it again to go to France this year in July? Or do I have to apply for a new Schengen for France?

My visa expires on 14 Sept 2014.

Comment: I think the "multi"-entry visa stands for multiple entries, so yes. A "single"-entry would not allow you to do so.

Comment: FYI, the correct spelling is "Schengen", not "Shengen".  I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

**Yes**, you can, that's why it's a *multiple* entry visa and not a *single* entry visa.  And because it's a *Schengen* visa, not a Greek visa, it's valid for all Schengen states.

That said, remember that the final decision to let you in will be made by immigration official, so you will still need a reason to visit, proof that you can afford to stay in Europe, some reason to return home, etc.